# Terraform GCP: Cannot add a service project into shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I use the following terraform script to add many service projects to a shared VPC. The terraform script is executed by a service account, which has org-level role "Compute Shared VPC Admin" and "Resource Settings Administrator". All service projects can be added into shared vpc except this one - "icomply-uat". The project name is correct, and I can use the service account to query the project detail as well. But some how, the following script return error.

**Terraform script:**

```
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "service_project_icomply-uat" {
    host_project    = google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host.project
    service_project = "icomply-uat"
}
```

**Error message:**

> Error: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/icomply-uat' was
> not found, notFound │ │   with
> google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project.service_project_icomply-uat,
> │   on main.tf line 283, in resource
> "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project"
> "service_project_icomply-uat": │  283: resource
> "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project"
> "service_project_icomply-uat" {

Comment: 1) Are you using the `google-beta` provider? 2) is `icomply-uat` the Project NAME or Project ID?